# Fluid Mechanics, a simplified simulation of fluids with a constant viscosity

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I've been racking my 16 year old brain for what seems to be a quite simple idea turned into something very complicated.

I'm creating a simulation program for a hobby project and I need to simulate simple fluid currents in a 2D grid.

A simple overiew:

I want be able to apply a velocity vector to a cell in the grid and have that vector propagate and create a current by affecting adjacent cells. That current of course should not propagate forever and dissipate somehow from the calculations.

How can I calculate the effects of the vector to other cells?

Simple illustration of implementation:[image]
I'm sorry if this is badly worded or formatted, it's a bit tricky to explain...

Comment: You need the [Navier-Stokes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations). And you'll need to take the [simplified to 2D case](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=navier+stokes+equation+2d).

Comment: This is a lot for my high school physics brain to process... Mind explaining the implementation of this equation to me for my case and/or giving me a simplified overview of how it works?

Comment: That's really too broad to be usefully answered here. If you do some Googling you should be able to find articles on solving the NS equations in a simplified way. Note that the NS equations remain a formidable computational problem and indeed there is [a million dollars waiting for anyone who makes significant progress in this area](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/navier%E2%80%93stokes-equation).

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help, I will do some googling. Although I'd like to keep the question open for anyone who would like to suggest an implementation of the scenario using an alternative method or a simplified NS equation.

Comment: Your diagram makes it look like you are asking about a [multiphase flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiphase_flow), which is a different problem than the rest of the body (which seems to be about the [finite difference method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method)). Can you confirm which you are interested in?

Comment: It isn't multiphase flow because I'm just treating the object as a different "layer". The object has it's own velocity but it is affected by the currents' velocities (They are added to the object velocity). The objects' movements to not alter the currents for simplification purposes. The objects can exert a force (apply a vector) to an adjacent cell however in the simulation but that's besides the point.

Comment: What you are doing here seems to be an attempt at [Computational Fluid Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics) which is an extremely powerful, but also quite complicated field.  You can't really escape solving differential equations.  As another comment mentioned; this looks like finite difference method, so there should be literature on using this method.  Adding an object and modelling it _somewhat accurately_ might be a problem if you don't use the right relationships.

Comment: Well maybe as long as the object moves semi realistically with the current it will be alright, right now the main goal is to be able to give one of those cells a velocity and have it propagate out.

Comment: ...This is a big jump from the usual high school gpe=mgh, f=ma crap... I guess it's an introduction to first year uni level physics and above...

Comment: @bi0phaz3 To put it into some perspective; I was taught about CFD techniques in 3rd year engineering courses.  It wasn't even really discussed in our introductory fluid mechanics course; we only started learning it in our "Fluid Dynamics" course, which had several pre-requisites.

Comment: Yep, CFD is Masters degree stuff, I might even just even omit the fluid simulations and implement other pragmatic solutions. This is after all, part of a biology hobby project and it's not _that_ important. (I'm creating a bacterial simulation program and the fluid simulations were to aid in more realistic movements of entities on the fluid. Also some bacterium are able to create currents if they have cilia to pull glucose particles towards them. I guess I'll just omit the realistic movement and use a more pragmatic way for the cilia and glucose)